# Wifi problem Broadcom BCM4352

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, lenovo, broadcom

I have a problem with getting the wifi on Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo Y50-70 to work. I have the problematic Broadcom BCM4352 card, I already installed the newest drivers, disabled the ideapad and done some other stuff I found on the internet, but still after some time of being connected to the network pings return Unreachable and I need to reconnect to network. I also heard that it may cause problem with freezes on Ubuntu, is it true?

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is a few months old. I'm sure somebody will find it of use.

Go to: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2262459&page=5

As long as you have at least Ubuntu kernel 3.19 then proceed to step 2 of post #44. I did it and it worked like a champ.

There is a bug (that I have noticed hasn't manifested itself lately... maybe it's fixed by now?) where Ubuntu will sometimes freeze when you hover your mouse over the wifi icon near your clock.